# Error al ejecutar un query. Necesito mostrar cuantas alarmas por operador

Tags: php, laravel-5, mariadb

Este es mi código :

```
public function alarmaAtendidaO()
 {
            $data = \DB::select('SELECT operadors.nombre AS Nombre, operadors.apellido AS Apellido,
            (SELECT COUNT(ala.id) FROM alarmas ala INNER JOIN operadors op ON op.id = ala.operador_id
              WHERE ala.operador_id=op.id) AS Cantidad de alarmas
                INNER JOIN  operadors ope ON ope.id = alarmas.operador_id
                INNER JOIN  empleados em ON em.id = ope.empleado_id
                INNER JOIN  usuarios usu ON usu.id = em.usuario_id
                INNER JOIN  personas per ON per.id = usu.id
                FROM operador opera');
            echo dd($data);
}
```

y me genera este error :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'de alarmas
INNER JOIN operadors ope ON ope.id = alarmas.operador_id
I' at line 3 (SQL: SELECT ope.nombre AS Nombre, ope.apellido AS Apellido,
(SELECT COUNT(ala.id) FROM alarmas ala INNER JOIN operadors op ON op.id = ala.operador_id
WHERE ala.operador_id=ope.id) AS Cantidad de alarmas
INNER JOIN operadors ope ON ope.id = alarmas.operador_id
INNER JOIN empleados em ON em.id = ope.empleado_id
INNER JOIN usuarios usu ON usu.id = em.usuario_id
INNER JOIN personas per ON per.id = usu.id
FROM operadors opera)
```

Comment: ese SQL no esta bien. no podria arreglarlo porque desconozco el modelo. Pero tenes un select, otro select que devuelve un valor, montones de inner join antes de un from. no esta bien.

Comment: y de paso mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Gracias en unos momentos me instruire

Answer (score 0):

El error que te muestra es porque el alias no lo estás encerrando en comillas y tienes varias palabras:

```
... WHERE ala.operador_id=op.id) AS "Cantidad de alarmas" ...
```

también podrías unirlas en una sola palabra con guiones bajos o *underscores*:

```
... WHERE ala.operador_id=op.id) AS cantidad_de_alarmas ...
```

Comment: Solo en ese alias o en todas tengo que tener las comillas . Me sigue dando error

Comment: estan mal ubicados los join shaz.. es mas complicado el problema...

Comment: Por eso dice la respuesta que estoy solucionando el error que el OP muestra.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con el siguiente query, si te funciona comenta para explicar unos detalles de como lo construiste, ya que tienes unos errores de semantica.

```
SELECT 
ope.nombre AS Nombre, 
ope.apellido AS Apellido, 
(SELECT COUNT(ala.id) FROM alarmas as ala INNER JOIN operadors as op ON op.id = ala.operador_id WHERE ala.operador_id = op.id) AS cantidad_alarmas
FROM operador as ope
INNER JOIN  alarmas as ala ON ope.id = ala.operador_id
INNER JOIN  empleados as em ON em.id = ope.empleado_id
INNER JOIN  usuarios as usu ON usu.id = em.usuario_id
INNER JOIN  personas as per ON per.id = usu.id ;
```